# How to forward an exception caught in 2 route to 1 route in apache camel

Tags: spring-boot, exception, error-handling, apache-camel, try-catch

I configured 2 routes A & B using Apache Camel. When I try to hit route A it will generate an XML template as a response which I forward to route B. In both routes, I have declared try-catch blocks to catch Exceptions. when there was an exception while generating a response in route B using the respective processor, it was caught by the route B catch block but could not forward the same exception to route A.

Route A:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:2222" + "/doc")
    .routeId(getFlowName())
    .doTry()
        .process(docmergeProcessor)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
        .to("http://localhost:1234/example?bridgeEndpoint=true")
        .to(logExchange("DOCUMENT"))
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST))
        .to(logExchangeWithException())
        .transform().simple("${exception.message}")
.end();
```

Route B:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:1234/" + example + "?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
        .doTry()
            .to(logExchange())
            .process(processor)
            .to(XSL_PATH)
            .to(logExchange())
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST))
            .to(logExchangeWithException())
            .transform().simple("${exception.message}")
    .end();
```